# Can not upload file in Windows 'open' window while headless mode is set to true

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, autoit-c#-wrapper

I faced a problem while trying upload file in headless mode through ChromeDriver v94. To upload my file I use AutoItHelper to control Windows 'Open' Window.

Code :

```
this.Web.Elements.ClickElement(SomeWindow.SelectButton); //Click to open Windows 'Open' uploading window.
AutoItHelper.OpenFileDialog($"{aFullPathToFile.xml");  // Upload file by windows dialog 'open'
```

If I run this on my local environment there aren't any problems, Window is found and file is uploaded successfully. Locally I run it with headless OFF mode. But in my CI way, tests are going in headless ON mode. On CI way (and if I use headless off mode in my local config) test can not find Windows 'Open' Window to upload file.

Error:

```
Exception message: [AutoIT could not locate file dialog window within given time.].
Exception:System.NotSupportedException: This exception was not expected in test. ---> System.TimeoutException: AutoIT could not locate file dialog window within given time.
         at CommandCenterTestsUtils.WindowsAutomation.AutoItHelper.OpenFileDialog(String filePath)
```

I was trying to give him more time to find this windows but there wasn't any result. Maybe I should use any chromeDriver option to get windows uploading 'open' dialog window handled?

Comment: Why do you `use AutoItHelper to control Windows 'Open' Window.` Could'nt you just upload it directly without opening dialog ?

Comment: Is it possible to push file through the button (which open dialog 'open' window) ? What do you mean ? Please describe your solution :)

Comment: Yes. It is possible.
But for now I have only code in AutoIt which use wd_core.au3 and wd_helper.au3. If you are interested to see the details, please provide some public url (without a need to login) which I should demonstrate how to automate them.

Comment: @MichałLipok Thanks for the tip.
I used 
`.SendKeys('pathToFile')`
method on my uplading file button and it works correctly. My file was uploaded successfully :)

Comment: As far as I remember in my/our AutoIt solutions we are not sending Keys, but binary content of the file.